# Secure XML Parsers

Tags: java, xml, security, xerces, owasp

In typical Java applications, the XML parsers is XALAN/XERCES but they were not written with security in mind. I am curious to know if there are parsers that are more robust when it comes to security.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'security in mind'? What do would you consider a secure XML parser?

In this [Parleys video](http://parleys.com/display/PARLEYS/Home#talk=31129602;title=The%20Threat%20is%20Out%20There!%20XML%20Threats%20and%20DataPower;slide=1) is a great talk about XML threats. Might give you some hints and concepts.

**Edit:** To answer your question: there are hardware solutions which can analyze your incoming HTTP, SOAP, etc communication and filter for virus attachments in SOAP, deliberately dangerous XML with large/infinite entity recursion etc.