# Most "SECURE" way of parsing XML in java

Tags: java, xml, security, xml-parsing

I have a requirement to select the "MOST SECURE" XML parsing library in Java related to "CYBER SECURITY".

How can i check which API library is most secure ?. I cannot select all the XML libraries & go through the specification for each and every library.
What are the requirements which i need to look into ? 
Where to start is what i am looking for.

I came across the link which provides some information about features of XML that can be exploited.
[xml vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906927/xml-vulnerabilities)

Any document or links related to Secure way of parsing the XML file would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take into account several security factors:

- The load of your application (DOS attack): DOM may be discouraged in favour of Sax [What is the difference between SAX and DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828703/difference-about-sax-and-dom)
- An xml vulnerability: [xml vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906927/xml-vulnerabilities)

You need to pay attention to the xml specifications supported by your library and take care of Exceptions.

This question is linked to :
[Secure XML Parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037798/secure-xml-parsers)

Answer (score 1):

Security is not a one-dimensional property. You can't say that one parser has 83 ounces of security and another has 98 ounces. So the notion that one parser is "more secure" than another is nonsense. You need to be specific about what kind of risks your are concerned about and what defences are offered by particular parsers against those risks.

For example, on some measures open-source code is more secure than closed-source (because it's available for inspection) but on other measures it's less secure (because it's easier for a hacker to install a back-door).

Answer (score 0):

Some comments/suggestion:

- I think its a good question for bringing out the topic of "**Secure XML Parser**". The mentioned link to another topic on the same forum, rightly lists the typical attacks which are possible by exploiting the way XML parsers  work.
- At the same time, the forum posting also points to [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335713.aspx), which apart from listing the type of attacks, suggests the **possible solutions** for getting around the problem.
- As per the post, the solution lies in the parsers themselves. Lets take for example, a typical way to attack using [xml bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs) is to **exploit inline DTD**. Inline DTD is a feature which almost all the parsers support and rightly so because there will be XML document  having DTD parsers. Certain class of application (*some standalone applications like batch processing etc*) will need this feature.
- At the same time parsers also provide the functionality to disable the DTD validation hence giving **flexibility** to the application developer to choose the usage depending on the use case.
- So IMHO there won't be anything called secure parser. The way your use/program makes is secure or unsecured. Way to proceed is keep in mind the vulnerabilities which programming your parsing.
- Its a typical approach for any generic framework. For example there are frameworks for web application. You can build a web application but the application will not be secure unless you program it to be. The framework will provide all the tools to make it secure.

Comment: There are many applications which accepts XML input from many different sources, out in the internet. Inputs of different applications will be different(different schema) but format is same i.e, XML. 

So as a second layer of security after firewall, we would like to parse the XML to check for any vulnerabilities. Later if it passes the generic security test only then we would allow those XML as input to applications. 
For the above requirement, the XML parsing library itself should be secure(less vulnerable to attacks). That is why i am looking for Most secure XML parsing library in Java.

Comment: Can some one give me some possible contenders for "SECURE XML parsers in Java".